# A mathematical representation of a circular list

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science, data-structure, function-spaces

An infinite list of elements of $S$ can be viewed as a function from the set $\mathbb N$ of all natural numbers to $S$.

By the way, in the field of computer science, a kind of infinite list, called a *circular list*, is sometimes used.  A circular list is a list in which there is no first and last element, and the sequence of elements is repeated infinitely.

My question is, is there any known mathematical counterpart of a circular list?  In particular, what mathematical function does a circular list correspond to?

Comment: Seems like you could define a “circular list” of elements of $S$ to be a periodic function $f:\mathbb Z \to S$.

Comment: A directed cycle graph is another related mathematical object. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is the list length, use $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, [in which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) indices satisfy $x+n=x$. You can then move $k$ places to the right by computing $x+k$ modulo $n$.